# How to open a URL logged from by a long running process in bash or zsh

Tags: bash, docker, pipe

I have this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 --pull always -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $HOME/livebooks:/data ghcr.io/livebook-dev/livebook
```

That will log something like this :

```
latest: Pulling from livebook-dev/livebook
Digest: sha256:32095aae51bbb4ed11c4c7a9bffcd1157b9f93ec3c8b90cc3c8abe79e56c8166
Status: Image is up to date for ghcr.io/livebook-dev/livebook:latest
[Livebook] Application running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/?token=u3yt4bc43roox6ziw33joymhyvwhnyxi
```

For some reason that output is `stderr`.

This is a long running process, and I would like to keep it that way so I can just kill it with `Ctrl+c`.

I would like to pipe it into `grep` or `rg` to get the URL and open that.

For now this is what I am doing:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 \
  --pull always -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
  -v $HOME/livebooks:/data ghcr.io/livebook-dev/livebook \
  2>&1 \
  | rg -m 1 -o 'http://.*' \
  | xargs xdg-open
```

But is there some `tee` or `cat` magic to get the web page to open but also have the full log (and future log) into the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you expected :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
        
container=livebook
{ while sleep 1; do
    url="$(docker logs $container 2>/dev/null | grep -Po 'Application running at \K(.*)')"
    test -z "$url" || break
  done
  open "$url"
} &
docker run --name $container -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 --pull always -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $HOME/livebooks:/data ghcr.io/livebook-dev/livebook 2>&1
```